# How to run same container on all Docker Swarm nodes

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm just getting my feet wet with Docker Swarm because we're looking at ways to configure our compute cluster to make it more containerized.
Basically we have a small farm of 16 computers and I'd like to be able to have each node pull down the same image, run the same container, and accept jobs from an OpenMPI program running on a master node.

Nothing is really OpenMPI specific about this, just that the containers have to be able to open SSH ports and the master must be able to log into them.  I've got this working with a single Docker container and it works.

Now I'm learning Docker Machine and Docker Swarm as a way to manage the 16 nodes.  From what I can tell, once I set up a swarm, I can then set it as the DOCKER_HOST (or use -H) to send a "docker run", and the swarm manager will decide which node runs the requested container.  I got this basically working using a simple node list instead of messing with discovery services, and so far so good.

But I actually want to run the *same* container on all nodes in one command.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker 1.12 introduced global services and passing `--mode global` to run command Docker will schedule service to all nodes.

Using Docker Swarm you can use labels and negative affinity filters to gain the same result:

```
openmpi:
  environment:
    - "affinity:container!=*openmpi*"
  labels:
    - "com.myself.name=openmpi"
```

Comment: Also with [Kontena](https://www.kontena.io) you can define your service's deploy strategy as 'daemon'. Then it will be deployed to every node. It will be also deployed automatically to all new nodes when they join the cluster.

Comment: is the example from docker-compose file? I think swarm mode does not work with compose

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the affinity filter is the _only_ predicate used, against every node, to decide if the container runs or not?  Thus, this implies, for every node, "if i am not running something called openmpi, run openmpi and give it the label name=openmpi".  Is that correct?

Comment: @dov.amir i'd like to know that too.  however, i believe that if it doesn't work with compose, it's still possible to specify these filters as command line options?

Comment: yes that --mode options does not work with compose.  Latter example is from docker-compose file. @Steve's assumption is right how it is going under the hood. Of course those filters can be specified as command line options as well `docker run --label="com.myself.name=openmpi" -e "affinity:container!=*openmpi*" ...`